# Facebook android SDK

Tags: android, facebook

I want to use this SDK, and I can not create project from existing source from the facebook dir.
And at importing this project I always get this error:

```
19:32:32 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read C:\AndroidManifest.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\AndroidManifest.xml (System could not find the file)
[2010-09-25 19:32:32 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Unable to read C:\AndroidManifest.xml: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\AndroidManifest.xml (System could not find the file)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under `Project->Properties->Android, try selecting 'Android 2.2'`

Comment: Had the same error, this solved it, thanks!